# Why Does Response Change From Post Request?

Tags: javascript, json, express, axios, next.js

**Problem:** `console.log(res.data)` gives a different result from `console.log(JSON.parse(res.request.response))`.

I am making a post request to an internal API from my Next.js app. It is a request to a REST endpoint that returns a list object. The data should look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "views": [ { "data1": 1 ...}, ...],
    "otherViews": [ {"data2": 1, ...}, ...],
  },
  ...
]
```

I am accessing the data from this request in the typical `then/catch` format. So

```
let internalServerResponse = axios.post(endpoint, body, config)
    return internalServerResponse
    .then(res => {
        let errors = null;
        let data = null;
        if (res.data.errors) {
            errors = res.data.errors;
        } else {
            data = res.data
        }
        return {
            errors: errors,
            data: data
        }
    } )
    .catch(err => {
        return {
            errors: err,
            data: null
        }
    })
```

The issue arises where the `views` list always returns an empty list, while the `otherViews` list seems to be unaffected.

```
{
    "identifier": "...",
    "views": [],
    "otherViews": [
        {
            "field1": "...",
            "field2": "...",
            "field3": "..."
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Looking at the `res.request.response` from the server, I see that the `views` list is not actually empty (as intended), and that the format the objects in the views list is similar to that of the `otherViews` list. The returned response (`res.request.response`) is valid JSON.

Console log output of `JSON.parse(res.request.response)`:

```
{
    "identifier": "...",
    "views": [
        {
            "field1": "...",
            "field2": "...",
            "field3": "..."
        },
        ...
    ],
    "otherViews": [
        {
            "field1": "...",
            "field2": "...",
            "field3": "..."
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

**What I Tried**

To debug, I tried:

- printing `res.data` which gives the missing views list
- printing `JSON.parse(res.request.response)` which gives the correct object
- setting my `data = JSON.parse(res.request.response)` which *still* somehow gives the missing view list

I am completely stumped. I have two questions:

- Why is res.data and JSON.parse(res.request.response) different?
- How on earth is the value changing when I assign it to a variable?

Comment: Very strange indeed. Could you post your network tab screen maybe? Do you have some axios plugins or interceptors enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the preview response of the network tab is the correct response. Still not sure why I cannot access the `views` list.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

The issue is resolved. Due to the way I was passing the resulting object, I was filtering through the `views` list that was referenced in the original `res.data` object.

Please see this for reference: [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)